# Restful Web Service - What happens when I run a DELETE request on a collection?

Tags: rest, web-services, restful-architecture

The REST architecture expects specific types of resources called "collection".
Since this type of resource is contemplated in REST it is assumed that requests can be made with all methods provided by the HTTP protocol: GET, POST, DELETE etc.
What I want to know is exactly what behavior you expect, in a REST architecture precisely, from a DELETE request on a collection.
The request will delete the resource collection so that if I run a new request on the that collection i will get an error resource not found? Or will the request cancel the "singleton" resources contained in the collection and then the resource collection still exists?

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you're mixing two things up: A REST request is an interface between your frontend and your backend and can be **GET**, **POST**, **PUT**, **DELETE**.

Then, everything you want to do with it needs to be implemented on the backend. However, there are strict principles on what to do with each:

- GET = fetch
- POST = insert
- PUT = update
- DELETE = delete

But, the REST requests are not doing anything in the database by default. In your method where the REST requests are coming in in your backend, you need to implement a method to fetch/insert/update/delete data you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think you misunderstood my question. I have never mentioned the database or almost any kind of query.
I just ask what is the expected behavior of an architecture strictly REST when a DELETE request is made on a collection resource: is the collection later empty or does not exist anymore?

Comment: Okey, I see. However, in a strict REST architecture there's a database action expected. So you usually use your collection (which you get from frontend) as identifiers on which data is to be deleted in a database. Basically my bullet points in the answer show the expected behavior. Since data is usually getting persisted in a database the usual behaviour is a database action.